# EC2ResponseError: 401 Unauthorized AWS was not able to validate the provided access for an ec2 instance

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, connection, boto

I have two ec2 instances A and B both in same region, security group etc. 
I use boto to perform connection.

**After updating boto from version 2.34.0 to version 2.35.0 I cannot connect to host from instance A, but able to connect from instance B.**

> `AuthFailure`AWS was not able to validate the provided access credentials

I have found out that possible reason of such issue is that boto [Switch elb/ec2 over to signature version 4](https://github.com/boto/boto/commit/32abe3e99961069912b5004e1507d40e785300ae)

How does that possible that I am able to connect from machine B, but couldn't connect from machine A ?( python code responsible for connection same on both instances)

What could cause such strange situation ? Thanks

Comment: I was getting the same error while running the "EC2 external inventory script". As @garnaat mentioned it happened to be the clock was misconfigured. I fixed it by using `sudo ntpdate -s time.nist.gov` on my ubuntu box.

Comment: Proceed on [that](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/set-time.html) page to setup ntpd for ec2 instances

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The SigV4 authentication method places a greater demand on keeping the clock on the requesting device in sync with the clock on the server.  It's possible that the clock on the instance that is no longer working has drifted past the 5 minute limit but is still within the 15 minute limit required by the previous SigV2 signing algorithm.

Try sync'ing the clock on both instances.